# Elasticsearch: Apply a lowercase on indexed data

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lucene

I have indexed documents in my elasticsearch. A sample document look like this:

```
{
    "_index": "processed_tweets",
    "_type": "processed",
    "_id": "830403820580663296",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "at": [
        "@LouisDasch"
      ],
      "original_tweet_id": "830398288352403457",
      "id_str": "830403820580663296",
      "trigrams": [
        "blessed lourdes lady",
        "lourdes lady feast",
        "lady feast day",
        "feast day wishing"
      ],
      "hashtags": [
        "#Catholic"
      ],
      "id_tweet_creator": "487735029",
      "tokens": [
        "blessed",
        "lourdes",
        "lady",
        "feast",
        "day",
        "wishing"
      ],
      "bigrams": [
        "blessed lourdes",
        "lourdes lady",
        "lady feast",
        "feast day",
        "day wishing"
      ],
      "retweeted": true
    }
  }
```

I would like to lowercase all the hashtags present in the field "hashtags" for all the document I have indexed.
For example I would have:
"hashtags": ["#Catholic"] -> "hashtags": ["#catholic"]
What is the best way (lesss time consumming) to update every keywords to their lowercase equivalent (conserving the "#")?

Comment: do they all follow the same structure?

Comment: @depperm Actually my solution is the total reindexation, but I would like to knoz if there is an alternative

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Some documents may have the original_tweet_id missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ES 5.0 and above, there is a scripting language called "painless" which is introduced. This may help you to update the fields. Its very fast in processing.

Check below link for more information.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-scripting-painless.html

Comment: "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "db0d481",
    "build_date" : "2017-02-09T22:05:32.386Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  }

Comment: Can you provide a more descriptive example?

Comment: //try something like this                                                                           
POST processed_tweets/processed/_update_by_query 
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.hashtags = ctx._source.hashtags.replaceAll(/#*/, m -> m.group().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))"
  }
}